# WooCommerce add order note to orderCompleted email

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am at my wits end here and have tried every solution I could find online for days and nothing works. The worst part is the problem should be solvable in about 4 lines of code but it just isn't working.

**What I need:**
When the order completed email goes out I want the order notes (not the customer notes, the actual Order Notes) added into the email. I can filter through them after but I cannot seem to get the notes to appear in the email at all. This is an example of an order note...on an order:
[image: order notes]

so far I have tried this code:

::PHP::

```
<?php
$comments = $order->get_customer_order_notes();
if($comments){
    echo '<h2>' . _e( 'Order Notes', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h2>';
    foreach($comments as $comment) {
        echo $comment->comment_content . '<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

which is basically what I need except its targeting the customer_order_notes, which are comments users add into the order when they place it. like: "my dog will pick up my package, his name is lucky"

I have also written a lugin to get the notes based off other peoples, the base is this:

::PHP::

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'bl_add_order_notes_to_completed_email', 10 );

function bl_add_order_notes_to_completed_email() {
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    // If the order is not completed then don't continue.
//    if ( get_post_status( $post->ID ) != 'wc-completed' ){
//        return false;
//    }

    $args = array(
        'post_id' => $post->ID,
        'status'  => 'approve',
        'type'    => 'order_note'
    );

    // Fetch comments
    $notes = get_comments( $args );

    echo '<h2>' . _e( 'Order Notes', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h2>';
    echo '<ul class="order_notes" style="list-style:none; padding-left:0px;">';

    // Check that there are order notes
    if ( $notes ) {
        // Display each order note
        foreach( $notes as $note ) {
            ?>
            <li style="padding:0px -10px;">
                <div class="note_content" style="background:#d7cad2; padding:10px;">
                    <?php echo wpautop( wptexturize( $note->comment_content ) ); ?>
                </div>

                <p class="meta">
                    <abbr class="exact-date" title="<?php echo $note->comment_date; ?>"><?php printf( __( 'added on %1$s at %2$s', 'woocommerce-customer-order-notes-completed-order-emails' ), date_i18n( wc_date_format(), strtotime( $note->comment_date ) ), date_i18n( wc_time_format(), strtotime( $note->comment_date ) ) ); ?></abbr>
                    <?php if ( $note->comment_author !== __( 'WooCommerce', 'woocommerce-customer-order-notes-completed-order-emails' ) ) printf( ' ' . __( 'by %s', 'woocommerce-customer-order-notes-completed-order-emails' ), $note->comment_author ); ?>
                </p>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

I don't really know why that isnt working. It looks like it should but it does nothing.

If anyne has a solution that will print those notes into my email...like seen in this image...I will love you forever.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried filter hook `woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields` ? Some references on [github](https://gist.github.com/craigsimps/98adff30f0ac68247d59) and [hookr.io](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields/)

Comment: The thing is I do not need to input and access new data; just add in the existing order note data to the email. I could do this but the same issue would occur: How do I access admin order notes? if I can get them the rest is solvable; have not found a way yet to input them into a variable

Comment: Well, looking at the code (of woocommerce's order completed email) it seems like what you want to implement is may be the default functionality.

Comment: If you problem is not yet resolved, may be [Add Order Notes To WooCommerce Completed Order Email](http://www.remicorson.com/add-order-notes-to-woocommerce-completed-order-email/) can help you.

Comment: I started with that article, which is just a guys ripoff of code made in an addon which I later found and built my own with, and 3 other sources I used to get them to display. none worked. Once I resolve it I will post a solution; but that article is garbage and full of php errors when you implement his code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this much later; but better than never. The final code I ended up using that worked and is still functioning as of today is the following:

```
?>
<h2><?php _e( 'Tracking ID', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
<?php 
$comments =  $order->get_customer_order_notes();
$customer_comments = $order->get_order_notes();

foreach( $comments as $comment ){
    if ( strpos( $comment -> comment_content, "MyTracking" ) !== false ){
        echo $comment -> comment_content . '<br />';
    }
}
foreach( $customer_comments as $comment_2 ){
    if ( strpos( $comment_2 -> comment_content, "filterText" ) !== false ){
        echo $comment_2 -> comment_content . '<br />';
    }
}
```

This was put inside the email template **customer-completed-order.php**, taken from the woocommerce plugin's **templates/emails/** directory. I placed the code in at the desired location and put the **customer-completed-order.php** file in my **child theme** in it's **root directory** within the following folders: **woocommerce/emails/customer-completed-order.php**

It then added both the customer and admin notes. I also added a filter, because my main goal was to get the tracking data posted to the admin order notes sent to the customer in their completed order email.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder called woocommerce in your theme folder. In this folder, create a new folder called emails, and in this folder duplicate the customer-completed-order.php from **wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails**. And add this snippet at line 51: Refer [this article](https://remicorson.com/add-order-notes-to-woocommerce-completed-order-email/)

```
<h2><?php _e( 'Order Notes', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

<?php
$args = array(
    'status' => 'approve',
    'post_id' => $order->id
);
$comments = get_comments($args);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo $comment->comment_content . '<br />';
endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this code to your functions.php:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'wc_add_order_notes_to_completed_emails', 10, 1 );
function wc_add_order_notes_to_completed_emails($order) {
    if ( $email->id == 'customer_completed_order' ) {
        echo '<h2>' . __( 'Order Notes', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h2>';
        $order_notes = $order->get_customer_order_notes();
        foreach ( $order_notes as $order_note ) {
            echo '<p>' . $order_note->comment_content . '<p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to achieve the same thing as Ecolis and came across a solution which may help other users. I simply wanted to echo an Order Note into an email. In my email template in my child theme folder I wrote the following code:

```
<?php echo wpautop( wptexturize( make_clickable( $customer_note ) ) );  ?>
```

Source of code - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/customer-note.php

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this older thread looking for a way to include the note that the customer places in "Order notes" on the checkout page in the Woocommerce New Order email received by the admin.

The code that @Martyn Gray posted above worked perfectly:

```
echo wpautop( wptexturize( make_clickable( $customer_note ) ) );
```

I copied the Woocommerce admin-new-order.php email template into my child theme and added it inside the existing code "user-defined additional content".

This is the original code:

```
/**
* Show user-defined additional content - this is set in each email's settings.
*/
if ( $additional_content ) {
echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( wptexturize( $additional_content ) ) );
}
```

This is the updated code:

```
/**
 * Show user-defined additional content - this is set in each email's settings.
 */
if ( $additional_content ) {
    echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( wptexturize( $additional_content ) ) );
echo wpautop( wptexturize( make_clickable( $customer_note ) ) );
}
```

The customer's note now appears on all Woocommerce emails including new order, invoice, etc.

WP v5.6.2
WC v5.0.0

Hope that helps anyone that follows.